# download needed files to aplication android

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android atudio, I recently make my first app, I put in many raw resources file(txt,mp3) that is why it's size is big (~200Mo).

I want to allow user to download what he need in order to benefit my service like listen to mp3 read text.

Comment: One does not call that download.

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully consider why you need this much data in your app, remove all unnecessary parts and put everything you really need into the .apk as resource.

If I find some app is downloading 200MB to my phone, I'll uninstall that immediately.

Comment: how can application download files after installation

Comment: I see that in many of application. if you want to play music for example which didn't exists application show you a dailogue to tell you that this file is not found, you have to download it